# How can i use a string to determine the location of an object within a list?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say i have a list of the alphabet

```
myList=["a","b","c"..."z"]
```

Now lets say we have a variable within a loop that takes out a random letter from the list. Obviously random is imported.

```
while True:  
ans=myList[random.randint(1,26)]
```

I want the user to be asked to take a guess at a letter so within the loop i add

```
guess=input('Take a guess at a letter from the alphabet')
```

The user will receive a clue on the whereabouts of the answer

```
print('The letter locates between x and x.')
```

Question. How can i determine the position of `ans` in `myList` so i can give two random values and perhaps assign them to variables, one below `ans` and one value over `ans`.

The `range` would always be random between these two values so `ans` is not always the median of the two values.

p.s. I would put the script together to give a better view of what it looks like, but unfortunately i find the formatting help very confusing, and highlighting pieces of code and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> does not work as simply as i expected.

Comment: Improved formatting and deleted useless text.

Comment: `x and x` -- are those numbers or letters? "Between 5th and 10th" or "Between E and J"?

Answer (score 0):

The position is the output of the random call, right?

You can save that to a variable before calling the `myList[]`

```
index = random.randint(1,26)
ans = myList[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
myList.index(ans)
```

for above code to work you need to have ans in myList or else it will throw an exception.
BTW this question is similar to [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)